# Logging out facebook user without access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an application where users authenticate with Facebook to post photos on their timelines. This application will run on single System where user will come authenticate and post photos.

My problem is to logout each user when they are done. So i am currently logging out by using `$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(CALLBACK_URI, $permissions);` i logout use when a new user go for authentication.

> Why i am not logging out user as soon as they are done?

Because i am using share dialog popup which closes automatically as soon user is done sharing.

I am looking for a way to logout user without the use of access token. Because if a user uninstall or change is their password the access_token becomes invalid and when logging them out it redirects to facebook.com/home.php

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to logout user without the use of access token.

That is not possible.

If it was, I could include a call to the logout URL into my website (for example as the `src` of an image), and thereby log out any person visiting my site from Facebook, without their agreement or their knowing.

---

Having an application on a single system for a multitude of users to login to Facebook with is not a good idea – it will easily trigger Facebook’s security systems into thinking that something shady is going on. And that leads to added hassle for your users (having to confirm their identity via additional steps/questions after login), potentially up to blockage of your app by Facebook.

If at all possible, go the way of letting users use their own devices, f.e. by providing free Wi-Fi at the event(?) location.

Comment: I changed my code and uses publish_action post content on user timeline. And you were right. Facebook started to annoy users with additional steps to confirm their login. And later blocking of my Ip Address (Temporary i guess) and showing messages to users `Possibly spam content too many users are sharing same content`. My event was 6 days long and posted about 1000+ photos. In the event their was another client doing same short of thing sharing 1000+ photos on each day. Facebook didn't block his IP and didn't annoy his users with additional security steps. How possibly can he do that?

Comment: He had similar setup as mine. All i know is he was not using Web SDK. Possibly using Unity or Android sdk